# Is there a way to format the Asset Size variable to Mb, Kb, etc.?

Tags: assets, format

I'm trying to display the file size of a file uploaded in Assets. I can get it to display the number of bytes in the file. https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/craft.assets#size

Is there a way to format that number to Mb's?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
{% set bytes = asset.size %}
{% set kiloBytes = (bytes / 1024)|round(2) %}
{% set megaBytes = (kiloBytes / 1024)|round(2) %}

bytes = {{ bytes }}
kiloBytes = {{ kiloBytes }}
megaBytes = {{ megaBytes }}
```

You can look at Twig's [number_format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html) filter if you want to get fancy with how to display the numbers.

Answer (score 7):

You now can use the `filesize` filter:
https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/filters.html#filesize.
This will make the file size readable, and the unit will be selected automatically.

Comment: As an extension to this answer, as it is specific to the question, as of `Craft 3.1.21` the `filesize` filter now formats using metric units: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#3121---2019-04-03

Comment: I've discovered that you can even round the `|filesize` filter by adding a round parameter: `|filesize(1)`. Maybe there's even more?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, the filesize filter is your friend: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/filters.html#filesize

Internally, this uses a yii Formatter. You can supply additional arguments to the filter. Here is a link to the function Craft is calling internally: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#asShortSize()-detail

Be aware that Craft's default base for calculating file sizes is 1000, not 1024. This lead to some unwanted results while I was working with it. I ended up overriding the global setting like this:

```
Craft::$app->formatter->sizeFormatBase = 1024;
```